# Excel VBA copy and paste selected text from word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want a macro button on my Excel sheet that:

1. I will highlight (select) some text in a word document
2. I press the button
3. the text is then copied and pasted into a specified cell in my excel sheet

I have tried:

```
sub paste()
    objword.selection.copy range("B2")
End sub
```

Firstly I don't know whether `objword` is the right syntax, and secondly everytime I select text in word, I cannot click on excel without the text deselecting, so how will I be able to do this? Do I have to create the macro in word?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering: How is that more comfortable than Ctrl+C/V?

Comment: Have a look here. This should get you started.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317885/using-vba-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-word-document-into-another-word-document

Comment: @Jelmer so should I be recording a macro in word and then referencing the excel file from there? I can't get a selection from word in an excel macro because clicking on excel deselects the 'selection'.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ because it would only require 2 actions : highlight and click button.

Comment: @newbie23 Much and complicated work for such a tiny "improvement". I bet you could do Ctrl+C/V for the next 10 years and still save time compared to writing that code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ok I thought it would be simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code (requiring a reference to Microsoft Word xx Object Library) running in Excel will grab the current selection in Word and copy the text into A1:

```
Sub paste()
    Dim oWd As Word.Application
    Set oWd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = oWd.Selection
    Set oWd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also, the following is the equivalent opposite, i.e. code that can run in Word that takes the selection in Word and sends it to Excel:

```
Sub paste()
    Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    oXL.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = Selection.Text
    Set oXL = Nothing
End Sub
```

This one requires a reference to Microsoft Excel xx Object Library.

Comment: thanks, not sure what you mean by requiring a reference to object library. Its throwing a compile error 'user-defined type not defined'

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend adding something that checks if Excel is open, just to be safe.