# Word macro error while copying contents from one document to another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy doc1 contents (formatted text and images) into doc2 where doc2 contains tables and I want to copy the contents of doc1 into the 18th cell in doc2.

I got the code from the below reference and modified it a bit accordingly. The working code is mentioned below:

Ref Link: [How do I copy the contents of one word document to the end of another using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434754/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-word-document-to-the-end-of-another-using-vba)

```
Sub copyContents()
    Dim wordWasRunning As Boolean
    wordWasRunning = IsMSWordRunning()

    Dim mswApp As Word.Application
    Set mswApp = AttachToMSWordApplication()

    Dim doc1 As Word.Document
    Dim doc2 As Word.Document
    Set doc1 = mswApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SingleDoc.docx")
    Set doc2 = mswApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\MergedDoc.docx")
    
    Dim destination As Word.Range
    Dim source As Word.Range
    
    Set source = doc1.Content
    Set destination = doc2.Content
    
    destination.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source
    
    doc2.Close SaveChanges:=True
    doc1.Close

    If Not wordWasRunning Then
        mswApp.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code is working when I'm using a different window and trying to copy the contents from doc1 to doc2 (and I ran macro from doc3).

**Problem:**
I tried to modify the code so that I can run the macro from the doc2 itself. But the modified code (mentioned below) is causing the error.

**Modified Code:**

```
Sub copyContents()
    Dim wordWasRunning As Boolean
    wordWasRunning = IsMSWordRunning()
    Dim mswApp As Word.Application
    Set mswApp = AttachToMSWordApplication()
    
    Dim doc1 As Word.Document
    Set doc1 = mswApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SingleDoc.docx")
    
    Dim source As Word.Range
    Set source = doc1.Content
    
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source
    
End Sub
```

**Erorr:**

> Error 5941: The Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist

*Line causing the error: `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source`
I tried to change the above line to the following trials (just to make it as close as the working code) but I got the same error (Error 5941)

Trial 1:

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source
```

Trial 2:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: Hi @PeterT , can you help me with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code is not written to be run from Word. If you are running it in Word, then the first four lines of code are completely unnecessary as Word is obviously running.

```
Dim wordWasRunning As Boolean
wordWasRunning = IsMSWordRunning()
Dim mswApp As Word.Application
Set mswApp = AttachToMSWordApplication()
```

Secondly, `Set doc1 = Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SingleDoc.docx")` causes `doc1` to become the active document, as you would see simply by looking at your screen. This is one reason that `ActiveDocument` needs to be used with great care. If you are running the code from the target document, then you can use `ThisDocument` instead.

```
Sub copyContents()
   
    Dim doc1 As Word.Document
    Set doc1 = Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SingleDoc.docx")
    
    Dim source As Word.Range
    Set source = doc1.Content
    
    ThisDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = source.FormattedText
    doc1.Close
    
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use a variable to refer explicitly to the target document.

```
Sub copyContents()
   
    Dim docTarget As Word.Document
    Set docTarget = ActiveDocument
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Set docSource = Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SingleDoc.docx")
    
    docTarget.Tables(1).Range.Cells(18).Range.FormattedText = docSource.Content.FormattedText
    docSource.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help and prompt response. The 2nd code worked for me.