# Append a word content to another word from excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format, excel-2010, copy-paste

I'm principiant and I'm trying to write a procedure (in excel VBA: i Need excel for other reasons that I'll not write here) that, given two paths of two word documents, appends the entire content of the first document (including tables and formatting) into the second one.

I've found some examples, but procedures based on "word.document" object doesn't seems to work for me (the macro execution stucks until a warning message regarding OLAP object is shown and it crashes). I would like to avoid the copy and paste method, and I tried with this procedure, it opens both documents, but doesn't copys anything... What's wrong?

```
Sub test()
    Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc1, wdDoc2 As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
    
    'controlla che il documento da aprire non sia già aperto
    Dim wDoc
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim fileName1, fileName2 As String
    fileName1 = "c:\test\b.docx" 'it is the source doc
    fileName2 = "c:\test\a.docx" 'it is the destination doc
    
    'verify that documents are not already opened
    For Each wDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If wdDoc1.Name = fileName1 Then
            GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    For Each wDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If wdDoc1.Name = fileName2 Then
            GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
   
    'debug only: I want to see what happens
    wdApp.Visible = True
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wdDoc1 = wdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=fileName1, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wdDoc2 = wdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=fileName2, ReadOnly:=False)
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
    
    
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    dim oTable As Object

    For Each oTable In wdDoc1
        Set oRange = wdDoc2.Content
        oRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oRange.FormattedText = oTable.Range
    Next oTable
    
    
    wdDoc1.Close
    wdDoc2.Close
'    Word.Quit
    Exit Sub
    
NO_WORD_FOUND:
    wdDoc1.Close
    wdDoc2.Close
'    Word.Quit
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc1 = Nothing
    Set wdDoc2 = Nothing
    MsgBox "error"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Following code is working fine for me:

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objWord, objDoc, objDoc2
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc =objWord.Documents.Open("Path\To\File1")
Set objDoc2 = objWord.Documents.Open("Path\To\File2")
objDoc.Activate
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory.Copy
objDoc2.Activate
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.EndKey wdStory
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
ActiveDocument.Save
```

Does this work? Partly sourced from - [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317885/using-vba-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-word-document-into-another-word-document)

Edit -

If creating the object doesn't seem to work for you, then you could try adding a reference to the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCplz.png)
Then, you can ditch the CreateObject function and directly call Word.Application instead. Also looks neater imo, but adding the reference is an extra step.

Comment: Thank you, but unluckily it doesn’t work for me. I already tried that code, I’ve searched within a lot of samples here but no one seems to work form me. 
I added the library “Microsoft Word 16.0”, but “Expected function or variable” error occurs when I try to run it, with the “WholeStory” word selected. However, I would prefer a solution that doesn’t use copy and paste method.
Anyone?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me, even if probably it isn't the best one:

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc1, wdDoc2 As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
    
    Dim wDoc
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim fileName1, fileName2 As String
    fileName1 = "c:\test\b.docx" 'it is the source doc
    fileName2 = "c:\test\a.docx" 'it is the destination doc
    
    'verify that documents are not already opened
    For Each wDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If wdDoc1.Name = fileName1 Then
            GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    For Each wDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If wdDoc1.Name = fileName2 Then
            GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
   
    'debug only: I want to see what happens
    wdApp.Visible = True
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wdDoc1 = wdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=fileName1, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wdDoc2 = wdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=fileName2, ReadOnly:=False)
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
    
    With wdApp
        .Visible = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        With wdDoc2
            .Range.Characters.Last.InsertFile fileName:=fileName1, Range:="", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, link:=False, Attachment:=False
        End With
        .Visible = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub
    
NO_WORD_FOUND:
    wdDoc1.Close
    wdDoc2.Close
'    Word.Quit
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc1 = Nothing
    Set wdDoc2 = Nothing
    MsgBox "error"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```